# Linux find always returns 1 record

Tags: linux, find, centos-6

Why command `find -cmin +20` in Linux CentOS always returns 1 record which is `.`?
How can I work around this?

Comment: It seems to work fine for me when I try a `find /path/to/search -cmin +20 -ls`  (-ls prints/list the found filenames. It is the default on many install but explicitly using it is a good idea. Same with the `/path/to/search` which defaults to `.`

Comment: yes, but try this: `find -cmin +20 | wc -l` it will always returns 1 even if your current catalog is empty.

Comment: `mkdir test`, `cd test`, `find -cmin +20 | wc -l`. My output is `0`.

Comment: What are the timestamps on both files `ls -la .` ?

Comment: hmmm...indeed, when I did same thing my result was `0` too. Weird, because in my existing catalog it always returns 1. I had to del mentioned catalog, and create it once again and now it works good. EDIT: described catalog was empty all the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't enter a specific path for `find` to look at, at least GNU find will default to search recursively from and including the current directory, i.e. `.`. Verbatim from `man find`:

```
If no paths are given, the current directory is used.
```

If you don't want to include the path argument itself in the results, add `-mindepth 1`. Once again from `man find`:

```
-mindepth levels
   Do not apply any tests or actions at levels less than `levels` (a
   non-negative integer). `-mindepth 1` means process all files except
   the command line arguments.
```

Example:

```
~$ mkdir test
~$ cd test
~/test$ find
.
~/test$ find -mindepth 0
.
~/test$ find -mindepth 1
~/test$
```

With your specific command, `find` will always return at least one record **if** the current directory itself is older than 20 minutes. Creating a new directory as you did will then not return anything, since it won't match the search criteria — at least not for 20 minutes after its creation.

Comment: Aye. That is why I asked "What are the timestamps on both files ls -la ." (one of those would be the dir itself). ;-)